# what happens behind the scenes of salesforce Asynchronous Apex?

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

Asynchronous apex will follow some kind of threading mechanism in behind the scene like Java or exactly how it will work. Your explanation would be great help for me.

Comment: How Salesforce handles it is not exposed to its Users or available a publicly documented resources. This question is too broad to be answered. But in summary, it does rely on multiple threads to process async operations. You may like to take a look at this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_introduction) to get more details on it.